# Can I set the Call Forwarding Settings via ADB?

Tags: android, adb, phone-call, ussd

I am trying to write a script using control android phone via `adb`, I figured how to make and receive call, sms , data ...etc, I would like to know if there is a way to configure the call settings, such as call forwarding/divert on busy / not reachable ...etc

I have a rooted phone, so access to `su` is available.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you know how to make a call already - so just dial proper [`USSD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data) codes to activate call diversion features you need.